# g++ issue with Magick++ and cygwin

Tags: g++, cygwin, imagemagick, magick++

When I try to compile a simple c++ file using Magick++ and cygwin, I keep getting this result:

```
$ g++ -o imageTest imageTest.cpp `GraphicsMagick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs`  
g++: unrecognized option `-no-undefined'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ldpstk  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I installed ImageMagick through the cygwin gui setup.

Answer (score 3):

GraphicsMagick and ImageMagick are two different libraries. If you want to build your program using ImageMagick, as you state, it's just a matter of changing

```
GraphicsMagick++-config
```

into

```
Magick++-config
```

This should work. As for GraphicsMagick, it looks like the current -devel library in Cygwin is broken, as it requires a library (libdpstk) which is no longer available. (Have a look [here](http://lists.xastir.org/pipermail/xastir/2006-December/010620.html) if you are interested.)